# ProtectedViewWindow Events are not firing in PowerPoint

Tags: office365, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

Office Version:  2303 (Build 16227.20280)

Below is a very simple project.   I subscribe to a few events, and write to the debugger.

I have some sample files that are guaranteed to display a ProtectedViewWindow, but the events still don't fire.

What am I missing?

```
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

namespace PowerPointAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private PowerPoint.Application theApp;
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            theApp = this.Application;

            theApp.ProtectedViewWindowActivate += TheApp_ProtectedViewWindowActivate;
            theApp.ProtectedViewWindowOpen += TheApp_ProtectedViewWindowOpen;
            theApp.ProtectedViewWindowBeforeEdit += TheApp_ProtectedViewWindowBeforeEdit;
        }

        private void TheApp_ProtectedViewWindowBeforeEdit(PowerPoint.ProtectedViewWindow ProtViewWindow, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TheApp_ProtectedViewWindowBeforeEdit");
        }

        private void TheApp_ProtectedViewWindowOpen(PowerPoint.ProtectedViewWindow ProtViewWindow)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TheApp_ProtectedViewWindowOpen");
        }

        private void TheApp_ProtectedViewWindowActivate(PowerPoint.ProtectedViewWindow ProtViewWindow)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TheApp_ProtectedViewWindowActivate");
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }
        
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you expect to see the debug output? Is that application run under the same security context (run as admin)?

Comment: Always a pleasure to see your name Eugene.   It turns out the problem is a bit different.  No ProtectedViewWindows are being opens.

Comment: So, do you get events fired correctly? Can you please confirm that?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev
I've reposted the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76132587/cannot-detect-read-only-state-of-active-document

Answer (score 0):

[**THIS IS NO LONGER AN ISSUE**]
It turns out that the alert being received was not a ProtectedViewWindow.

Will pursue new question in different thread.