# Cannot detect READ-ONLY state of active document

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

Looking for a C# solution I can use through VSTO.  We're running Windows 10 and Office 365

When we open a PowerPoint file from SharePoint, we get the following alert.
[image: READ-ONLY Message]

If you were to check the *ReadOnly* property of the *Presentation* object, it would have a value of **false**

The problem is that we have code that executes based on whether or not the *ReadOnly* property of the active Presentation is true or false.

My guess is that this *ReadOnly* state is happening in a different window similar to the *ProtectedViewWindow*

How can I programmatically check for the *READ-ONLY* shown in the above image?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Subsystem for Linux you can 'programmatically' check if a file is readonly by looking at the file's permissions displayed by the `ls -la` command. If the file is read-only, then the permissions will be `-r--r--r--` or `-r--------`.

The first set of permissions (-) indicates the file type (d for directory). The next set of three (r--) indicates the read permissions for the owner of the file, the second set (r--) indicates the read permissions for the group, and the third set (r--) indicates the read permissions for others.

If there is no w in any of the three sets of permissions, it means the file is read-only. If there is a w in any of the sets of permissions, it means the file is not read-only and can be modified.

You could use this command in a bash script programmatically.

In C#:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Prompt the user to enter the file path
        Console.Write("Enter the file path: ");
        string filePath = Console.ReadLine();

        // Check if the file is read-only
        if (File.Exists(filePath) && (File.GetAttributes(filePath) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is read-only.", filePath);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not read-only.", filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how the code works:

1. The code prompts the user to enter the file path. You can also statically set that as avariable.
2. The code checks if the file exists and is read-only using the `File.Exists()` and `File.GetAttributes()` methods. If the file exists and is read-only, it is considered read-only.
3. If the file is read-only, the code prints a message indicating that the file is read-only. Otherwise, the code prints a message indicating that the file is not read-only.

Comment: We have a VSTO Add-In using C#.  I would need to be able to do it through there.

Comment: In C# you can use System.IO classes that provide all the required functionality for that. For example, the [File.GetAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getattributes?view=net-7.0) function returns the `FileAttributes` of the file on the path where you can find whether the file is read-only or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can read `Presentation.FullName` property to get the file name, and check if the file is read-only, comes from a shared drive, or whether mark-of-the-web is set:

```cs
    static bool CheckMarkOfTheWeb(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var alternateDataStream = fileStream
                    .GetAlternateDataStream("Zone.Identifier", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                return alternateDataStream != null;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            // Handle file access or stream-related exceptions.
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Handle other exceptions.
            return false;
        }
    }
```

To check if a file comes from a network drive, use something like the following:

```cs
    static bool IsFileFromNetworkDrive(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            string drivePath = Path.GetPathRoot(filePath);
            DriveInfo driveInfo = new DriveInfo(drivePath);
            return driveInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Network;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Handle exceptions, such as invalid file path or drive access issues.
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'll try that out.